# How do you create an Salesforce aura component that is compatible for mobile view on app builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am unable to find any resource online that tells me the format or syntax to make an aura component mobile compatible.

Even a basic component with the below code shows up as only available for desktop on the lightning app builder.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
</aura:component>
```

See screen snippet below where the app builder shows the component with only the desktop compatibility. I would expect it show both the desktop and phone icons.

[image: ComponentWithOnlyDesktopSupport]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [Design](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) file, specify the supportedFormFactors.

```
<design:component label="Hello World">
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" />
    <design:supportedFormFactors>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type="Small"/>
    </design:supportedFormFactors>
</design:component>
```

Once you do this, your component will be available for mobile/tablet form factors. Also note that the default mode is support whatever forms the app your building supports.

> If you don’t declare form factor support for a component, then by default, it supports the same form factors as the page types that it’s assigned to. App and record pages support the Large and Small form factors. Home pages support only the Large form factor.